# Run python script as a service on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, python, upstart

I am facing the following  problem. I want to run a python script as a service on Ubuntu 11.10 system (already mentioned in the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705564/python-script-as-linux-service-daemon/10948190#10948190)

Query is marked as closed there. Thats why posting it here now.

I followed the steps mentioned in the above mentioned link, but i got the following error message in syslog:

```
init: script main process (21826) terminated with status 1
Jun 8 16:59:55 bilbo kernel: [263012.984531] init: script main process ended, respawning
Jun 8 16:59:55 bilbo kernel: [263013.044099] init: script main process (21827) terminated with status 1
```

The above two lines are getting repeated all the time.

On saying `sudo start script`, I get the following:

```
$ sudo start script
script start/running, process 21826
```

Following is the content of my `script.conf` placed in `/etc/init`:

```
description "Used to start python script as a service"
author "bilbo"
start on runlevel [2]
stop on runlevel [06]
exec python /home/bilbo/scripts/webserver.py
respawn
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong? Do I have to change my python code as well?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984847/need-init-d-script-for-python-application

Comment: Was able to solve it.
Just add chdir /home/bilbo/scripts above exec statement.
change exec statement to exec python webserver.py
That was it. :)